# Get time with hour, minute, second, millisecond, microsecond

Tags: java, date

I have this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

I know that this code return hour, minute, second in the time.
How i can get also the  millisecond and microsecond??

Comment: It can be done, see my answer.

Comment: Why is this -2???  I see no reason to downvote this question

Comment: When I published it users was fighting on it, it was -3 and then +1...
Sometimes users reduce points just because they high rated if you know what i mean...

Comment: I think it's more about your attitude.

Comment: +1 because I also do not see any reason to downvote!

Comment: Are you after generating a string (formatting) with microseconds or after parsing a string with microseconds into a date-time object?

Comment: For new readers to this question I strongly recommend that you don’t use `SimpoleDateFormat`. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. Use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't have microseconds, because a Date stores the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1 1970. For the milliseconds, use `S`, as documented in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: So, you think it is so obvious that there are not microsecond??

Comment: It's not obvious, and that's why I explain it in my answer. It's pretty clear if you read the documentation, though. Did you read it?

Comment: @lolo - Based on how it says "Millisecond" in the first table on the page that JB Nizet linked to?  Yeah, I'd say so.

Comment: If there had been a way of getting microseconds via SimpleDateFormat, it would have been there, in that table.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to get micro-seconds is to parse the string yourself.  Note: `Date` should be used to store micro-seconds, but you can use a `long`. (which you can also use for milli-seconds or nano-seconds)

```
private static final String YEARS_TO_MINUTES = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
private static final SimpleDateFormat YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF = new SimpleDateFormat(YEARS_TO_MINUTES);

public static long parseMicroSeconds(String text) throws ParseException {
    long timeMS;
    synchronized (YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF) {
        timeMS = YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF.parse(text.substring(0, YEARS_TO_MINUTES.length())).getTime();
    }
    long microSecs = 0;
    if (text.length() > YEARS_TO_MINUTES.length() + 1) {
        double secs = Double.parseDouble(text.substring(YEARS_TO_MINUTES.length() + 1));
        microSecs = (long) (secs * 1e6 + 0.5);
    }
    return timeMS * 1000 + microSecs;
}

public static String formatMicroSeconds(long timeMicroSeconds) {
    String dateTime;
    synchronized (YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF) {
        dateTime = YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF.format(new Date(timeMicroSeconds / 1000));
    }
    long secs = timeMicroSeconds % 60000000;
    return dateTime + String.format(":%09.6f", secs / 1e6);
}


public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    String dateTime = "2011-01-17 19:27:59.999650";
    long timeUS = parseMicroSeconds(dateTime);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        System.out.println(formatMicroSeconds(timeUS += 175));
}
```

prints

```
2011-01-17 19:27:59.999825
2011-01-17 19:28:00.000000
2011-01-17 19:28:00.000175
2011-01-17 19:28:00.000350
2011-01-17 19:28:00.000525
```

You can do similarly if you need nano-timings.

Comment: Hi Peter, I understand this is off topic, but curious to know why YEARS_TO_MINUTES_SDF was synchronized.

Comment: @Mahesh SImpleDateFormat is not thread safe.  It usually works fine without synchronization, but every so often you will get a corrupt value as it has mutable fields.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only show the millisecond: `:SS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss:SSSSS");
        for(int i=0; i<=5;i++) {
            System.out.println("Class 1 : " + ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter));
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77336
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77483
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77487
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77490
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77493
Class 1 : 19:25:19:77496
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java-doc of SimpleDateFormat, it tells :
Millisecond : S

Microseconds are not available.

Answer (score 0):

This example gets millisecond. Microseconds isn't available.

```
Date someDate = sDate.parse(dateString);
Calendar c = Calendar.setTime(someDate);
int millisecond = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the milliseconds are given with capital s and in your case it will be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS`. For more info refer to [Customizing formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)