# Wrong Output for java.text.SimpleDateFormat while Reading "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ"

Tags: java, simpledateformat, formatter

I was trying to convert the date in String format into java.util.Date by using java.text.SimpleDateFormat, however it's not giving me the right output. Please help!

My input is generated by Django date: ex. "2014-01-20T07:17:06.150995+00:00"

But, I got "Mon Jan 20 15:***19:36*** GMT+08:00 2014" instead of "Mon Jan 20 15:***17:06*** GMT+08:00 2014"

Here's my testing code:

```
String s = "2014-01-20T07:17:06.150995+00:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf;
String fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ";
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt, Locale.US);

String result = "";
try {
    Date date = sdf.parse(s);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, date.toString());
    result = date.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "date formatting error" + e.getMessage());
}
Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "date test >> " + result);
```

Comment: Looks like a timezone thing to me.

Comment: @HotLicks: A 2.5minute time zone?

Comment: I am testing this code on my Android Device (Nexus 7). Is there any difference?

Comment: Executing this on Ideone it gives an unparseable date error, so i'm guessing you need to sort the format string out;
http://ideone.com/e.js/8R1NGM

Comment: @bobbel: Check again. The hours are the same, the dates differ by 2.5 minutes.

Comment: When posting sample code, please remove extraneous code such as your setting of 'result' var and calls to Log. Present the simplest possible example of your problem.

Comment: @HeronYang Yes, there is a big difference between running on Android and running on official Java platforms. Android is a copy of Java, but is not an official implementation and has not passed the requisite compatibility tests. The Android libraries are very close copies but not exact clones of Java. You should add a tag to the question for 'Android'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see your two dates differ by 2.5 minutes.

This happens because you are parsing microseconds as milliseconds. This will add 150000 milliseconds to your result, or 2.5 minutes.

There is no standard way to parse a date string with microseconds using `SimpleDateFormat`, you will have to do it yourself if you can't get the source string in a different format.

If the date is always in exactly this format you could do something like:

```
String dateWithoutMicros = s.substring(0, s.length() - 9) + s.substring(s.length() - 6);
Date date = sdf.parse(dateWithoutMicros);
```

Comment: if so, how can I solve this problem? I think this site should help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits

Comment: That question is about formatting, not parsing, so it won't really help.

Comment: Nice! Ok, I will remove the 3 digits. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Keppil exactly the answer I needed

Comment: You might want to check out [setLenient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-).  More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746771/simpledateformat-leniency-leads-to-unexpected-behavior

Answer (score 2):

As I first tried to run your Code (replaced Log.d with System.out.println()) i got a ParseException: Unparseable date.

Next I tried several parts of the date with their respective format string parts. Lastly the problem was the timezone part "+00:00" respectively "ZZZZZ".

I read about the pattern letters in the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and found:
Z -> -0800
X -> 08; -0800; -08:00
So swapped your ZZZZZ with X and then it worked fine for me.
Final format string:
`String fmt = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX";`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the java.util.Date & .Calendar and java.text.SimpleTextFormat classes. They are notoriously troublesome.

## Joda-Time

Using the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library, you can pass that [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted string directly to a constructor. No need for formatters and parsers.

However, like java.util.Date, Joda-Time has a **resolution of milliseconds**. So it can handle only the first 3 digits of your fraction of a second. Fortunately though, rather than through an exception, Joda-Time simply truncates (ignores) the latter extra fractional digits.

```java
String s = "2014-01-20T07:17:06.150995+00:00";
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( s );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTime in UTC/GMT: " + dateTime.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-01-19T23:17:06.150-08:00
dateTime in UTC/GMT: 2014-01-20T07:17:06.150Z
```

## java.time.* Classes

The new classes bundled with Java 8, in the java.time.* package, supplant the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes. They are inspired by Joda-Time but are entirely re-architected. JSR 310 defines these classes.

These new classes have a **resolution of nanoseconds** rather than milliseconds, so they can handle all six of your fractional digits. Like Joda-Time, they take an ISO 8601 string directly.

```java
String s = "2014-01-20T07:17:06.150995+00:00";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( s );

System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
```

When run…

```
zdt: 2014-01-20T07:17:06.150995Z
```