# SimpleDateFormat leniency leads to unexpected behavior

Tags: java, date, parsing, string-formatting, simpledateformat

I have found that [`SimpleDateFormat::parse(String source)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)'s behavior is (unfortunatelly) defaultly set as lenient: [`setLenient(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-).

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds.

If I set the leniency to `false`, the documentation said that with strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format. I have used paring with `SimpleDateFormat` without the lenient mode and by mistake, I had a typo in the date (letter `o` instead of number `0`). (Here is the brief working code:)

```
// PASSED (year 199)
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("03.12.199o"));
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("03.12.199o"));        //WTF?
```

In my surprise, this has passed and no [`ParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) has been thrown. I'd go further:

```
// PASSED (year 1990)
String string = "just a String to mess with SimpleDateFormat";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("03.12.1990" + string));
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("03.12.1990" + string));
```

Let's go on:

```
// FAILED on the 2nd line
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("o3.12.1990"));
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("o3.12.1990"));
```

Finally, the exception is thrown: `Unparseable date: "o3.12.1990"`. I wonder where is the difference in the leniency and why the last line of my first code snippet has not thrown an exception? The documentation says:

> With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

My input clearly doesn't *strictly* match the format - I expect this parsing to be really strict. Why does this (not) happen?

Comment: You can, of couse, use `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("03.12.199o", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));` instead, which will exhibit the strict behavior for the entire string as you seem to desire.  Be aware that `mm` in a date format, both in SimpleDateFormat and in DateTimeFormatter, is minutes, not months;  you probably meant `MM`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this (not) happen?

It’s not very well explained in the documentation.

> With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret
>   inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict
>   parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

The documentation does help a bit, though, by mentioning that it is the `Calendar` object that the `DateFormat` uses that is lenient. That `Calendar` object is not used for the parsing itself, but for interpreting the parsed values into a date and time (I am quoting `DateFormat` documentation since `SimpleDateFormat` is a subclass of `DateFormat`).

- `SimpleDateFormat`, no matter if lenient or not, will accept 3-digit year, for example `199`, even though you have specified `yyyy` in the format pattern string. The documentation says about year:

  > For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year
  >   is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using
  >   the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.
- `DateFormat`, no matter if lenient or not, accepts and ignores text after the parsed text, like the small letter `o` in your first example. It objects to unexpected text before or inside the text, as when in your last example you put the letter `o` in front. The documentation of `DateFormat.parse` says:

  > The method may not use the entire text of the given string.
- As I indirectly said, leniency makes a difference when interpreting the parsed values into a date and time. So a lenient `SimpleDateFormat` will interpret 29.02.2019 as 01.03.2019 because there are only 28 days in February 2019. A strict `SimpleDateFormat` will refuse to do that and will throw an exception. The default lenient behaviour can lead to very surprising and downright inexplicable results. As a simple example, giving the day, month and year in the wrong order: `1990.03.12` will result in August 11 year 17 AD (2001 years ago).

### The solution

VGR already in a comment mentioned `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. In my experience `java.time` is so much nicer to work with than the old date and time classes, so let’s give it a shot. Try a correct date string first:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.mm.yyyy");
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("03.12.1990", dateFormatter));
```

We get:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03.12.1990' could not
>   be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor:
>   {Year=1990, DayOfMonth=3, MinuteOfHour=12},ISO of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

This is because I used your format pattern string of `dd.mm.yyyy`, where lowercase `mm` means minute. When we read the error message closely enough, it does state that the `DateTimeFormatter` interpreted 12 as minute of hour, which was not what we intended. While `SimpleDateFormat` tacitly accepted this (even when strict), `java.time` is more helpful in pointing out our mistake. What the message only indirectly says is that it is missing a month value. We need to use uppercase `MM` for month. At the same time I am trying your date string with the typo:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("03.12.199o", dateFormatter));
```

We get:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03.12.199o' could not
>   be parsed at index 6

Index 6 is where is says `199`. It objects because we had specified 4 digits and are only supplying 3. The docs say:

> The count of letters determines the minimum field width …

It would also object to unparsed text after the date. In short it seems to me that it gives you everything that you had expected.

### Links

- [`DateFormat.setLenient` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient-boolean-)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive and clen answer. I appreciate the effort. :))

Answer (score 3):

Leniency is not about whether the *entire* input matches but whether the format matches. Your input can still be `3.12.1990somecrap` and it would work.

The actual parsing is done in `parse(String, ParsePosition)` which you could use as well. Basically `parse(String)` will pass a `ParsePosition` that is set up to start at index 0 and when the parsing is done the current index of that position is checked.

If it's still 0 the start of the input didn't match the format, not even in lenient mode.

However, to the parser `03.12.199` is a valid date and hence it stops at index 8 - which isn't 0 and thus the parsing succeeded. If you want to check whether everything was parsed you'd have to pass your own `ParsePosition` and check whether the index is matches to the length of the input.

Comment: Do you mean that the strict parsing is not strict at all?

Comment: @Nikolas, well it depends on what you consider strict. Basically with strict parsing your input must start with a datetime that exactly matches the pattern. A lenient parser would deal with things like overflows (`30.02.2018` -> `2.3.2018` or `13:59` -> `13:59` even if your format states that hour needs to be in 1-12 am/pm format) etc.

Comment: With the word "strict" I mean that there is nothing stricter. I expect the String must exactly match the pattern with no extra character allowance. Now I understand the leniency in `DateFormat`. Thank you for the helpful answer. :))

Comment: @Nikolas you could use a library like Apache Commons Lang's `DateUtils#parseDateStrictly()` or roll your own (which basically just checks the `ParsePosition`.

Comment: I don't like util-classes with a bunch of static methods and there is no need to add a dependency just for one specific use-case. However, it's good to know there something like that exists - thank you again. :))

Answer (score 1):

If you use `setLenient(false)` it will still parse the date till the desired pattern is meet. However, it will check the output date is a **valid** date or not. In your case, `03.12.199` is a valid date, so it will not throw an exception. Lets take an example to understand where the `setLenient(false)` different from `setLenient(true)/default`.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); 
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("31.02.2018"));
```

The above will give me output: `Sat Mar 03 00:00:00 IST 2018`

But the below code throw ParseException as `31.02.2018` is not a valid/possible date:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.parse("31.02.2018"));
```