# Convert String to Date "2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00" in android

Tags: java, android, datetime, iso8601

I am just trying to convert "**2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00**" but getting exception. Can anyone suggest me DateFormat like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" to parse the string into Date.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, that would include the full Java stack trace for your exception, along with all code associated with that stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that the code below will help you

```
String dateString = "2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", Locale.getDefault());
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = format.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: You're going to get an exception with that.  You forgot the seconds.

Comment: Not really. I get 00 instead of 47 seconds. Thanks for the remark. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys. @DavidRauca

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00" )
```

## java.time

Use the modern *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

The legacy classes wore limited to millisecond resolution while the *java.time* classes have much finer resolution, nanoseconds. That is more than enough for the microseconds in your input string.

Your input complies with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern at all.

We parse your input as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) since it includes an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00" ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2016-01-28T12:08:47.676706-05:00

To see that same moment as UTC value, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-01-28T17:08:47.676706Z

Or adjust into a time zone, to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-01-29T06:08:47.676706+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

To generate Strings in other formats, search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class. Already covered many times.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).