# java SimpleDateFormat parse millis format error

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I want to parse the string data `"2016-06-08T10:27:17.369000000000Z"`, with

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import scala.util.Try
object TimeParse extends App {
  val raw = "2016-06-08T10:27:17.369000000000Z"
  private def parseDate(inputdate: String) = {
    val fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSSSS'Z'""")
    val myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy年MM月dd日 HH:mm:ss")
    Try(myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputdate)))
  }

  val r = parseDate(raw)
  println("r - " + r)
}
```

But output:
`r - Success(2016年06月04日 04:27:29)`

If I remove millis format, it will be right, as this:

```
object TimeParse extends App {
  val raw = "2016-06-08T10:27:17Z"
  private def parseDate(inputdate: String) = {
    val fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'""")
    val myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy年MM月dd日 HH:mm:ss")
    Try(myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputdate)))
  }

  val r = parseDate(raw)
  println("r - " + r)
}
```

Output :
`r - Success(2016年06月08日 10:27:17)`
why millisecond will get a fail result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `SimpleDateFormat` does not the seconds and milliseconds values as a decimal number.

It processes them separately, and therefore `17.369000000000` is not 17 seconds and 369 milliseconds but 17 seconds and 369_000_000_000 milliseconds.

The milliseconds value is then truncated to int and therefore is interpreted as -367_187_456 milliseconds, which is added to your date value (2016-06-08T10:27:17) and so you get a timestamp that is before your actual date.

See also [java.util.Date format SSSSSS: if not microseconds what are the last 3 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits)

Comment: I suddenly hit on how does 369_000_000_000 can truncated to -367_187_456 ?

Comment: @LoranceChen SimpleDateFormat reads this number as long value and then casts it to int (something like `System.out.println((int) 369_000_000_000L);`, which prints out `-367187456`)