# Datetime parsing error

Tags: java, android, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am having problem parsing dates in Java. Below is the code.

```
 String dateString = "2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z";
 List<String> formatStrings = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'");

    for (String formatString : formatStrings)
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString);
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date d = formatter.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println("Format is:" + formatString);
            System.out.println("Orignal Date: " + d);
            System.out.println("Orignal MS: " + d.getTime());

            return d;
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {}
    }

    return null;
}
```

When I run this program, I get the following output.

```
Format is:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'
Orignal Date: Fri Dec 22 03:45:15 UTC 2017
Orignal MS: 1513914315904
```

I am not sure why it is giving me **Dec 22** when it should be **Dec 13**. But if I change my input date to this.

```
String dateString = "2017-12-13T16:49:20.7Z";
```

i.e only one character before the Z. then I get the correct output.

```
Format is:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'
Orignal Date: Wed Dec 13 16:49:20 UTC 2017
Orignal MS: 1513183760007
```

It gives me correct output till 3 numbers before the Z. If more than 3 numbers than I got the wrong output.

It would be great if someone can point me out what I am missing here.

*PS: I am parsing these dates in android. I have set min API level to 16 and java.time is not available for API level below 26.*

Comment: Related: [java.util.Date format SSSSSS: if not microseconds what are the last 3 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`S` in `SimpleDateFormat` specifies a number of milliseconds, not a fraction of a second. You've specified 730555904 milliseconds, which is ~8.45 days - hence the date change.

`java.util.Date` only has a precision of milliseconds. I would recommend using the `java.time` package, which has a precision of nanoseconds, like your input. Use `DateTimeFormatter` for parsing. Note that in `DateTimeFormatter`, the `S` specifier *is* for fraction-of-a-second.

Even better, `Instant.parse` uses the right format anyway:

```
import java.time.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String text = "2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(text);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another Jon Skeet answer on the perplexities of time

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem. I will try that and test it again.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed: I've now added sample code. Whether you want to parse it as an `Instant` or not is a different matter, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you very for the sample code. I will first try using Instant.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using it on android where my min API level is set to 16. And I am getting an error that it requires API 26. Is there any other library which I can use it to parse? Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is, ThreeTenABP, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah ThreeTenABP works for me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. Since the release of Java-8 (Mar 2014), it is highly recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

> I am not sure why it is giving me **Dec 22** when it should be **Dec
> 13**.

This is a great example of how much error-prone `SimpleDateFormat` can be. `SimpleDateFormat` considers the fraction-of-second part as the number of milliseconds. Let's see the amount of duration by which it causes deviation from the correct date-time in your case.

```
import java.time.Duration;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(730555904);
        System.out.println(String.format("%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds %d milliseconds",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toMillisPart()));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
8 days 10 hours 55 minutes 55 seconds 904 milliseconds
```

Now, you understand why you got **Dec 22** instead of **Dec 13**. Let's see how clean and correct solution `java.time` provides you with.

### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter`

`java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z`).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z");
        System.out.println(instant);

        // or parse it to a ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z");
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // or parse it to an OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z
2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z
2017-12-13T16:49:20.730555904Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.