# FastDateFormat parser outputs incorrect time

Tags: java, timestamp, apache-commons

I've been scratching my head trying to understand why the FastDateFormat parser is returning a very incorrect time. The string timestamp I'm trying to convert is in GMT/UTC, and I'm trying to insert it into a Timestamp column in DB2.

Here's the code:

```
String gmtTimestamp = "2017-03-12 02:38:30.417000000";
FastDateFormat fdf = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS", TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
java.util.Date d = fdf.parse(gmtTimestamp);
Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp(d.getTime());
System.out.println(ts1);
```

The time that's printed is: "2017-03-16 17:28:30.0", 4 days and nearly 15 hours off. What's happening here?

Comment: Which version of apache.commons are you using?

Comment: commons-lang3 version 3.4

Comment: A guess without knowing `FastDateFormat`: 417000000 is interpreted as milliseconds, it’s about 4.8 days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798849/datetime-parsing-error). I know that other question is using `SimpleDateFormat`, but those two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

```
    String gmtTimestamp = "2017-03-12 02:38:30.417000000";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");
    Instant i1 = LocalDateTime.parse(gmtTimestamp, dtf)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(i1);
```

This prints

```
2017-03-12T02:38:30.417Z
```

The implicit call to `Instant.toString()` produces date and time in UTC (for our purpose the same as GMT), so you recognize the date and time from your GMT string.

### java.time

I recommend you drop the `java.sql.Timestamp` class. It is long outdated, and today we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. The original purpose of `Timestamp` was to store and retrieve date-time values to and from SQL databases. With a sufficiently new JDBC driver (JDBC 4.2), you can and will want to take advantage of two classes from `java.time` for that purpose: `Instant` for a point on the timeline and `LocalDateTime` for date and time without time zone.

In case you do need a `Timestamp` (for instance for a legacy API or an older JDBC driver you don’t want to upgrade just now), convert the `Instant` from above to `Timestamp` just before handing it to the legacy API or the database:

```
    Timestamp ts1 = Timestamp.from(i1);
    System.out.println(ts1);
```

Running in America/Chicago time zone this prints:

```
2017-03-11 20:38:30.417
```

`Timestamp.toString()` grabs the JVM’s time zone setting and outputs the date and time in this time zone (which may be confusing).

### What was happening in your code snippet?

`FastDateFormat` uses `SimpleDateFormat` format patterns. In `SimpleDateFormat` and `FastDateFormat` capital `S` means milliseconds. so 417000000 was taken as milliseconds (where you intended 417 milliseconds), it is rpughly the same as 4 days 20 hours, which were added to the date-time value up to the seconds. I reproduced your result using a `SimpleDateFormat` and setting my JVM to America/Chicago time zone. Other time zones that are -5 hours from UTC in March will produce the same result. Since the `Timestamp` was printed at offset -5:00, the apparent difference in the output was a bit less than the real difference of 4 days 20 hours, “only” 4 days 15 hours.

By contrast, though the modern `DateTimeFormatter` mostly uses the same format pattern letters, to it capital `S` means fraction of second, which is why we get 30.417 seconds as expected and desired.

### Quotes

> All patterns are compatible with SimpleDateFormat (except time zones
>   and some year patterns - see below).

([`FastDateFormat` documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html))

> `S    Millisecond     Number  978`

([`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))