# How to parse ISO date with microsecond precision in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, date, datetime, iso

I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217193/6727914

```
val df1: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
val string1 = "2022-12-29T19:59:20.783357Z"
val result1: Date = df1.parse(string1)
```

But it does not work:

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
> "2022-12-29T19:59:20.783357Z"  at java.text.DateFormat.parse (:-1)
> at FileKt.main (File.kt:13)   at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1)

I can't use `Instant.parse(date)`

The date "2022-12-29T19:59:20.783357Z" is a valid Iso8601String where 783 is the milliseconds and 357 is the micro seconds

Comment: It doesn't match the format you provide; it's not clear what you expect. `S` is for milliseconds, there's 1000 of them per second, and `783357 > 1000`.

Comment: Did you consider looking at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html? It's not clear why this is tagged Java/Kotlin if you're using Dart references :shrug:

Comment: @DaveNewton The questions title is how to parse ISO date in kotlin, the expectation is thus having the date parsed. The date provided is a valid ISO date, not sure what is not clear

Comment: The biggest point of misclarity is why microseconds are included in your string, but completely absent from the format string (I don't know if `SDF` handles microseconds, but the format string ignores them, hence the error).

Comment: _I can't use Instant.parse(date)_ Why not? SimpleDateFormat does not offer microsecond precision.

Comment: Due to API requirement 26, my app is 21. Can't upgrade it due to various constraints

Comment: So you either need to not add microseconds (do you really need microsecond "precision"?), or you need to handle it manually.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't need microsecond tbh, but the data is coming from another app that generates it with a built in function of the language that includes the microsecond by default, no option to exclude that

Comment: Then you'll need to handle it manually--yank anything between the `SSS` and the last char and parse normally, optionally filling the micros back in?

Comment: Can you use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)? It will make (most of) java.time available to you also when developing for API 21. See [this answer by Arpit Bhoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73023269/5772882).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` can not handle fraction-of-second up to microseconds resolution, its limit is up to millisecond resolution. If you try to parse it as it is, you will get the wrong result as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74932671/10819573).

You have two choices:

1. Truncate fraction of second up to milliseconds resolution.
2. Use ThreeTenABP or [Android desugaring support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/10819573). You can then use [`Instant#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) to parse your date-time string into an `Instant`.

**Note:** You need to use `X` instead of `Z` in your pattern.

**Demo**:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        var df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        var string1 = "2022-12-29T19:59:20.783357Z";
        string1 = string1.replaceAll("(\\.\\d{3})\\d+", "$1");
        var result1 = df1.parse(string1);
        System.out.println(result1);
    }
}
```

**Output in my time zone, Europe/London**:

```
Thu Dec 29 19:59:20 GMT 2022
```

### Solution using java.time API

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var instant = Instant.parse("2022-12-29T19:59:20.783357Z");
        System.out.println(instant);

        // For any reason, if you need java.util.Date
        var date = Date.from(instant);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/bCkleR)

Comment: The recommended java.time solution is available for API level 21 through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring).