# String to datetime conversion is failing

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

The conversion of the string to datetime is failing.
The data in the dataframe has the following format: `"2020-08-05T12:34:10.800046"`.
I used pattern `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`

```py
config_df.withColumn(
    "modifiedDate",
    F.to_timestamp(config_df["modifiedDate"], "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"),
).show()

+------------+
|modifiedDate|
+------------+
|        null|
+------------+
```

The execution works without problem but all values in the updated column are `NULL`. Which format should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is quite good, but would be nice to share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, so we can run the code ourselves and help you. Which format is in the dataset? What is the complete error message?

Comment: thanks for the hint. I dont get any error it is just returning NULLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits), `SSS`is for milliseconds. Therefore, it matches the first 3 digits `800` in your `800046`, no matter how many `S` you add.

I couldn't find any pattern that match your date, so you first need to update your string to keep only 3 digits at the end. With a regex for example

```py
a = [
    ("2020-08-05T12:34:10.800123",),
]
b = ["modifiedDate"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, b)

df.withColumn(
    "modifiedDate",
    F.to_timestamp(
        F.regexp_extract(
            "modifiedDate", r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}", 0
        ),
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
    ),
).show()


+-------------------+
|       modifiedDate|
+-------------------+
|2020-08-05 12:34:10|
+-------------------+
```